# Mongoose Schema Ref & Populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I would like to populate my database query with a set of documents from the same collection. Having never referenced before I can't tell if the error is in my model or in my query.

My current schema looks like this,

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    shortid = require('shortid')

/* Calendar Schema */
var CalendarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    'default': shortid.generate
  }, 
  title:String,
  mixin: [{_id: { type: String, ref: 'calendarlist' }}],
  notes: Array
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('calendarlist', CalendarSchema)
```

My sample docs looks like this,

```js
{
    "_id" : "mixtest",
    "mixin" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "calendarlist",
            "$id" : "cVkKRkNtB-"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "mix test",
    "__v" : 3,
    "notes" : []
}

and


{
    "_id" : "cVkKRkNtB-",
    "title" : "found doc",
    "__v" : 3,
    "notes" : []
}
```

and my query looks like this,

```js
calendarlist.find({}).populate('mixin').sort({
              title: 1
            }).exec(function(err, s) {
              if (err) {console.log(err) }
              console.log(s)})
```

Suggestions, tips or general clarifications totally appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) shows that the way to do reference is for example like below:

`fans: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]`.

Have you tried the following?:

```
mixin: [ { type: String, ref: 'calendarlist' }],
```

Also, the name of your model is 'calendarlist'. Is your collection called 'calendarlists'? Because 'Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name' per [this link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html).

Comment: remove the extraneous _id

Comment: Same error - { CastError: Cast to string failed for value "DBRef {
  _bsontype: 'DBRef',
  namespace: 'calendarlist',
  oid: 'cVkKRkNtB-',
  db: undefined }" at path "_id"......

Comment: Sorry - yes...tried -  mixin: [ { type: String, ref: 'calendarlist' }],

Comment: Shouldn't your collection be called calendars and your model Calendar?

Comment: calendarlist has been working for me over all...but it does show up as calendarlists in Mongo. I haven't literally referenced calendarlists anywhere in my code before.

Comment: Considering the 'db: undefined ' error, I wonder if you included 'mongoose.connect('mongodb://<host>:<port>/<db>');' .

Comment: In the end, I was not referencing in the actual document properly - "mixin" : [ "id1", "id2", "id3", etc]. @Treefish-Zhang thanks very much for the help and support.